# C: int function returns wrong value

Tags: c, return

I've looked over similar questions but didn't find appropriate answer.

I'm implementing a C code that should read a large number (stored in `char*`), and check if its divisible by 3.

Program works fine, it prints out valid answer (you'll see `printf`'s in a function which work as they should)

I even tried defining  1 and 0 and returning it that way, but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ONE 1
#define ZERO 0

int isdiv3(char* s, int sum)
{
  /*if string is empty, then check if sum until that point is divisible by 3*/
  if(strlen(s) == 0) {
      if((sum % 3) == 0) {
          printf("yes %d\n", sum);
          return ONE;
      }
      else{
          printf("no %d\n", sum);
          return ZERO;
      }
  }

  if(strlen(s) == 1)
  {
      if(!strcmp(s, "3") || !strcmp(s, "6") || !strcmp(s, "9"))
      {
          return ONE;
      }
  }

  int temp = s[strlen(s) - 1] - '0';
  sum += temp;
  s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';

  return sum + isdiv3(s, sum);
}

int main()
{
  int x;

  char str[200] = "123456";
  char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
  strcpy(s, str);

  x = isdiv3(s, 0);

  if(x == 1)
      printf("%s is divisible by 3\n", str);
  else
      printf("%s is not divisible by 3\n", str);

      printf("x %d\n", x);
//prints x 92

  return 0;
}
```

My question is> how it is possible that when `return 1` or anything else is in code, it prints out some random number.

Comment: **char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);** Maybe you will **free** it some day.

Comment: I didn't copy entire code, it's freed in the end, but I forgot to put it here. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't print a "random number", it prints the value you returned.

The sequence of return statements (with `sum` replaced by its value at the time) is:

```
return 6 + isdiv3("12345", 6)

    return 11 + isdiv3("1234", 11)

        return 15 + isdiv3("123", 15)

            return 18 + isdiv3("12", 18)

                return 20 + isdiv3("1", 20)

                    return 21 + isdiv3("", 21)

                        return 1
```

so , working backwards, the value returned is `1 + 21 + 20 + 18 + 15 + 11 + 6`, which works out to `92` as you see.

If you are still unsure then replace the `return` statement with:

```
int r = isdiv3(s, sum);
printf("return %d + %d\n", sum, r);
return sum + r;
```

I think you meant your return statement to be `return isdiv3(s, sum);` in which case the return value will always be `0` or `1`.

BTW the `#define ONE 1` etc. stuff is rubbish, just use `1` and `0` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `isdiv3` function contains a control path that leads to this return statement

```
 return sum + isdiv3(s, sum);
```

Obviously, in general case this control path returns neither `0` nor `1`. This is exactly what you observe, apparently.

Comment: I am aware of that, but, in the final passing trough `isdiv3` it enters first `if` condition, and the value should be returned from there.

Comment: Yes, but that value of 0 or 1 (the macros make no difference) is passed back to the call that returned `sum + isdiv3(s, sum)`, then *that* is (eventually) returned back to `main`.

Comment: @user3735245: I don't know what "final passing" you are talking about. But your function is recursive. Its "final passing" is the outermost recursive call. And it goes through `return sum + isdiv3(s, sum)`, not through any of the `return`s under `if`. The result of the outermost `return sum + isdiv3(s, sum)` is what you see in your `x`.